# Make text wrap around and not increase width

Tags: html, css

I have a div, and inside is a textarea and a div:

```
<div class="innotate">
        <div class="innotate-form">
          <div class="">
            <textarea cols="30" rows="3" name="body"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="instructions">Some Text that is quite long but should wrap instead of lengthening the div</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I want my `div.instructions` to wrap around and not increase the width of my `div.innotate`.

I'm quite stumped on this. I know `display: inline` isn't what I need, and setting the width manually is not an option.

I want the textarea to decide the width. That means that the width of my parent div should be at most the width of my textarea.

http://jsfiddle.net/8fo6by8d/1/

Comment: Can we use javascript or it can be done with CSS only?

Comment: @murnax I'd prefer a CSS only solution if at all possible

Comment: @Secret i really don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for an answer for this question and found that another way to do this with out setting any min/max width to the container div is to add

`max-width: fit-content`

to the div around the text. And add

`display: inline-block`

to the container around the text and the textarea

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .innotate-form {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .instructions {
    max-width: fit-content;
  }
</style>

<div class="innotate">
  <div class="innotate-form">
    <textarea cols="30" rows="3" name="body"></textarea>
    <div class="instructions">Some Text that is quite long but should wrap instead of lengthening the div</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fit-content has only okay support. for firefox you'll want to add a prefix, and it is still listed as 'experimental'. Internet Explorer has no support, if your site still needs to support it (business applications, for example)

Answer (score 0):

Used flex box for this one, had to throw width into .innotate-form for good measure.

```
.innotate-form {
  display: flex
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 14em;
  margin-top: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(249,249,249,0.9);
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 12.5px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fo6by8d/4/)

Answer (score 0):

er. wait.  You are physically setting the width of the text area at "cols" = 30.  One good turn deserves another.  When you set the width of the text area, set the width of .instructions to match.  In fact, lets do it one better, all without JS.

see http://jsfiddle.net/8fo6by8d/5/

Lose the col= setting

```
<div class="innotate">
    <div class="innotate-form">
        <div class="">
            <textarea  rows="3" name="body"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="instructions">Some Text that is quite long but should wrap instead of lengthening the div</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.innotate-form {
  margin-top: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(249,249,249,0.9);
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 12.5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.innotate-form .instructions {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #f20;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 5px;
}

textarea {
    width: 250px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 3px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

And if you're upset at having to type in a width twice there is always

```
textarea, .innotate-form .instructions{
    width: 250px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This would have been perfect only if the text expanded to the width of the text area.

Comment: Expanded?  What do you mean by expanded? I take the word expanded to mean grow the length of the string with the addition of more words.  Or, are you talking about enlarging font size so there is no space at the end of the text?  Or perhaps injecting more spacing between words (like an old word processor with right justify) ?  Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Also with flex, but German's didn't seem to work. This one uses a container instead. The text doesn't wrap, though. It just sizes with the container.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.innotate-form {
    flex: 1;
    margin-top: 3px;
    background-color: rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.9);
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 12.5px;
}
.instructions {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #f20;
}
textarea {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/77mdg9fq/)

EDIT: I researched more and found CSS3's `resize` property. This will make any div behave like a text area, so it will squish the text. I used flex to make the text area occupy the entire area of the div, then disabled resizing on the *actual* textarea.

[Can I Use?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/veojs9ed/1/)

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-resize: both;
    -moz-resize: both;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 400px;
    height:300px;
    background: darkorange;
    padding: 1em;
}
.innotate {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
}
.instructions {
    padding: 1em;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: red;
}
textarea {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    resize: none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this CSS

.innotate-form .instructions {

```
font-size: 14px;
color: #f20;
min-width: 250px;
max-width: 250px;
padding: 5px;
word-break: break-all;
```

}